# Problem with centering an image using MaterializeCSS

Tags: html, css, image, alignment, materialize

I am making a website as a school project and I have added an image that I can't center. I've tried over 10 ways of centering it but nothing works. It just stays on the left side of the screen. I am using Materialize CSS. All of the HTML and CSS is below. P.S. How can I add the same picture to the navbar so it fits? I've tried a couple of ways but it didn't work.

```css
nav {
    background-color: #271675 !important;
}

.naw-wrapper {
    position: sticky;
    z-index: 1;
}

.buttons {
    margin-top: 15vh;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}

.title {
    color: #543cc0 !important;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    margin-top: 2vh;
}

p {
    color: #646464;
}

.text {
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
}

.btn {
    font-size: 25px !important;
    margin: 5px;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    border-radius: 7px;
}

.buildGuide {
    margin-top: 20vh;
}

.buttons .text {
    margin: 3vh;
    margin-left: 10vw;
    margin-right: 10vw;
}

img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}

.modal-content .title {
    margin: 0;
}

.buttons .title {
    font-family: 'Courier Prime', monospace;
}

.components {
    margin-bottom: 15vh;
}

.left-arrow,
.right-arrow {
    border-radius: 100%;
    color: white;
    background-color: #543cc0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 5vh;
}

.left-arrow {
    float: right;
}

.right-arrow {
    float: left;
}

.carousel {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
    height: 30vh;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!--CSS and meta tags-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Courier+Prime&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>PC Configurator | Home</title>

</head>

<body>
    <!--Navbar-->
    <nav>
        <div class="nav-wrapper">
            <a class="brand-logo">PCC</a>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <!--Top text and buttons-->
    <div class="row buttons" id="topText">
        <div class="col s12 m12 l12 center-align">
            <img class="responsive-img" src="C:\Users\Jakov\Desktop\edit\zadnjiProjekt\resources\logo.png">
            <p class="text flow-text">PC Configurator is a webiste designed to make PC building easy and accessible to
                everyone.
                We have a selection of PC building guides and tools at your disposal. The best part - it's totally
                free!</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn deep-purple darken-4 waves-effect flow-text">Build a PC<i
                    class="material-icons right flow-text">build</i></a>
            <p class="text">OR</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn deep-purple darken-4 waves-effect flow-text">Auto Builder<i
                    class="material-icons right flow-text">edit</i></a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--Building guide-->
    <div class="buildGuide row">
        <div class="col s12 m12 l12 center-align">
            <p class="title flow-text">Choosing the right components</p>
            <p class="text flow-text">Choosing the right components for your brand new PC can be hard, especially if you
                know nothing about PCs. In this guide, we will show you all you need to know about PC components. Simply
                click on one of the components to learn about it.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--Carousel-->
    <div class="carousel components center-align">
        <div class="carousel-item col s12 m6 l3 center-align">
            <a class="waves-effect waves-light modal-trigger title flow-text" href="#cpuModal">
                <img src="C:\Users\Jakov\Desktop\edit\zadnjiProjekt\resources\cpu.png" class="responsive-img">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item col s12 m12 l3 center-align">
            <a class="waves-effect waves-light modal-trigger title flow-text" href="#gpuModal">
                <img src="C:\Users\Jakov\Desktop\edit\zadnjiProjekt\resources\gpu.png" class="responsive-img">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item col s12 m12 l3 center-align">
            <a class="waves-effect waves-light modal-trigger title flow-text" href="#mbModal">
                <img src="C:\Users\Jakov\Desktop\edit\zadnjiProjekt\resources\mb.png" class="responsive-img">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item col s12 m12 l3 center-align">
            <a class="waves-effect waves-light modal-trigger title flow-text" href="#ramModal">
                <img src="C:\Users\Jakov\Desktop\edit\zadnjiProjekt\resources\ram.png" class="responsive-img">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item col s12 m12 l3 center-align">
            <a class="waves-effect waves-light modal-trigger title flow-text" href="#storageModal">
                <img src="C:\Users\Jakov\Desktop\edit\zadnjiProjekt\resources\storage.png" class="responsive-img">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item col s12 m12 l3 center-align">
            <a class="waves-effect waves-light modal-trigger title flow-text" href="#psuModal">
                <img src="C:\Users\Jakov\Desktop\edit\zadnjiProjekt\resources\psu.png" class="responsive-img">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item col s12 m12 l3 center-align">
            <a class="waves-effect waves-light modal-trigger title flow-text" href="#caseModal">
                <img src="C:\Users\Jakov\Desktop\edit\zadnjiProjekt\resources\case.png" class="responsive-img">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item cl s12 m12 l3 center-align">
            <a class="waves-effect waves-light modal-trigger title flow-text" href="#coolingModal">
                <img src="C:\Users\Jakov\Desktop\edit\zadnjiProjekt\resources\cooling.png" class="responsive-img">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row center-align">
        <div class="col s6 m6 l6">
            <i class="small material-icons flow-text center-align left-arrow" id="prev">keyboard_arrow_left</i>
        </div>
        <div class="col s6 m6 l6">
            <i class="small material-icons flow-text center-align right-arrow" id="next">keyboard_arrow_right</i>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--Modals-->
    <div>
        <!--CPU-->
        <div id="cpuModal" class="modal">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <p class="title flow-text">Processor</p>
                <p class="text flow-text">The processor, also know as the <b>CPU</b>, is the brain of your computer.
                    It does
                    all of the calculations and operations you throw at it. There are only two processor brands.
                    <b>Intel</b> and <b>AMD</b>. While both of them make good processors, Intel is better for
                    gaming, while
                    AMD is better for workstations. You should spend between 20% and 30% of your budget on your
                    processor.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--GPU-->
        <div id="gpuModal" class="modal">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <p class="title flow-text">Graphics card</p>
                <p class="text flow-text">The graphics card, also known as the <b>GPU</b>, is probably the most
                    important
                    component if you are want a gaming or workstation based PC. There are two graphics card chip
                    makers:
                    <b>Nvidia</b> and <b>AMD</b>. There are also a lot of 3rd party brands that use those chips and
                    just
                    make the rest of the graphics card. Those are the ones you will most likely find, as the
                    so-called
                    <b>"founder's edition"</b> graphics cards(that are entirely 1st party) are very rare. You should
                    spend
                    around 40% of your budget on your graphics card. Some processors have integrated graphics, and
                    don't
                    need dedicated graphics cards. Those processors have a <b>G</b> at the end of their name(AMD) or
                    don't
                    have <b>K</b>, <b>X</b> or <b>F</b> at the end of their name(Intel).</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--Motherboard-->
        <div id="mbModal" class="modal">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <p class="title flow-text">Motherboard</p>
                <p class="text flow-text">The motherboard makes all of your components communicate. Every component
                    is
                    plugged into it. They all differ mainly by their <b>chipset</b> and <b>socket</b>. Depending on
                    which
                    CPU you have, you will need a different socket(<b>AM</b> for AMD and <b>LGA</b> for Intel). It
                    is
                    recommended that you spend less than your CPU on your motherboard. For most users, the
                    motherboard
                    features don't even matter.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--RAM-->
        <div id="ramModal" class="modal">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <p class="title flow-text">Memory</p>
                <p class="text flow-text">Memory, also known as <b>RAM</b> is where all of your running apps are
                    stored.
                    Once you power off the computer, the memory get wiped clean. There are multiple aspects too look
                    for
                    when choosing memory.<br>
                    <b>Memory speed</b> measures how often your memory communicates with your CPU(measured in MHz).
                    AMD
                    CPUs benefit much more from higher memory speed. It is recommended to have a memory speed of
                    3000MHz or
                    higher for AMD CPUs.<br>
                    The <b>latency</b> or <b>CAS timing</b> is how much cycles it takes for your RAM to send data
                    requested
                    by the CPU. Generally, everything below <b>CL-20</b> is considered OK, and everything below
                    <b>CL-17</b>
                    is considered fast.<br>
                    The <b>number of memory sticks</b> affects your performance the most. It simply tells you how
                    many
                    sticks of RAM you are getting in the package. One is Ok for simple tasks, but having two or more
                    significantly increases performance, as long as you install them in <b>dual-channel mode</b>.
                    The
                    possible amount of ram sticks can be 1, 2, 4, 8, 16 and even 32. Most computers use 1-4 RAM
                    sticks since
                    that is what most motherboards support.<br>
                    The <b>capacity</b> of your RAM simply tells you how much <b>GB</b> of RAM you are getting. 4GB
                    is
                    enough for very slight tasks, 8GB is enough for some gaming or every-day tasks, 16GB is OK for
                    most
                    games and workstation applications while 32GB+ is only used in expensive beastly computers that
                    can
                    handle everything you throw at them.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--Storage-->
        <div id="storageModal" class="modal">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <p class="title flow-text">Storage</p>
                <p class="text flow-text">The storage does what the name says - it stores all of your data, even
                    when
                    your
                    PC is off. There are 3
                    types of storage: <b>SSD</b>, <b>HDD</b> and <b>hybrid</b> drives. SSDs are the fastes of them
                    all
                    by a
                    lot. They don't have as much storage as the other parts and cost more. HDDs are the slowest but
                    they
                    have the most storage and cost the least. Hybrid drives or SSHDs are a hybrid of the two. They
                    are
                    faster than HDDs but slower than SSDs but have more storage than SSDs. Their cost is somewhere
                    inbewteen
                    the two. There are mulpitle for factor: <b>3.5"</b>(HDDs and SSHDs), <b>2.5"</b>(SSDs),
                    <b>M.2</b>(SSDs), and <b>PCIe</b>(SSDs).</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--PSU-->
        <div id="psuModal" class="modal">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <p class="title flow-text">Power supply</p>
                <p class="text flow-text">The power supply, or the <b>PSU</b> is responsible for powering your
                    system.
                    <b>Modular</b> PSUs have all the cables seperate, so you can only plug in the ones you need.
                    <b>Non-modular</b> PSUs have all the cables attached. It is important not to cheap out on your
                    PSU
                    and
                    only buy from trusted brands. Those brands are: <b>Corsair</b>, <b>Coolermaster</b>,
                    <b>Asus</b>,
                    <b>Gigabyte</b>, <b>Silverstone</b>, <b>be quiet!</b>, <b>Phanteks</b>, <b>Thermaltake</b>,
                    <b>Seasonic</b> and <b>Fractal Design</b>. You should always get a PSU with more wattage than
                    you
                    need.
                    For example, if your system uses 400W you should get a 550W PSU. Better PSUs also have power
                    ratings.
                    These tell you how good their power efficiency is. They start with <b>80+</b> and go all the way
                    up
                    to
                    <b>80+ Platinum</b>.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--Case-->
        <div id="caseModal" class="modal">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <p class="title flow-text">Case</p>
                <p class="text flow-text">The case houses all of your components. The only performance factor of
                    cases is their airloflow. Some come with preinstalled fans, more intake space and much more. The
                    case is often the cheapest part of any PC.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--Cooling-->
        <div id="coolingModal" class="modal">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <p class="title flow-text">Cooling</p>
                <p class="text flow-text">Most of your components need cooling. Some of them, like the CPU, GPU and
                    PSU usually come with one or more fans. But sometimes that is not enough, especially for more
                    powerful hardware. There are 3 types of coolers. <br><b>CPU coolers</b> cool the CPU. They can
                    be water coolers or air coolers.<br><b>GPU coolers</b> cool the GPU. Most GPUs come with
                    excelent air-cooling but you can step it up further with a custom water cooler.<br><b>Case
                        coolers</b> or <b>case fans</b> are as they sound - fans that are mounted inside the case
                    and help with the intake of cold air and with the exhaust of hot air.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--Scripts-->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>

</html>
```

[image: The image I want to center]

Answer (score 0):

first of all you should add the logo img tag and then display the navbar as flex. after that you can use the justify-content:center; . don't forget to resize the logo dimensions in your css styling

example

```css
nav {
    background-color: #271675 !important;
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
}
```

the html code

```html
    <!--Navbar-->
    <nav>
        <div class="nav-wrapper">
            <img class="pcclogo"src="https://i.ibb.co/mb1Mjqy/logo.png">
        </div>
    </nav>
```